# ios-UIBezierPath stroke by percentage for anti-clockwise with start for arc is from vertical downward position

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to create anticlockwise UIBezierPath with start of arc is negative y axis (just for visualization).
[image]

```
let arcPathForLayer = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: upperCenterPoint, radius: radius, startAngle: arcPathStartAngle, endAngle: (arcPathEndAngle), clockwise: false)
```

Normally for **clockwise** `UIBezierPath`, start and end angle is **0.0pi** and **2.0pi** respectively -for if the path is to start form positive x axis.
 
But for this case where `UIBezierPath` is **anti clockwise** and start of arc is **negative y axis** -the start angle and  end angle is little confusing to calculate.
So I will post the answer for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the visualization for solution:
[image: here is the picture]

So the start angle is **0.5pi** and end is **-1.5pi**, 
now for drawing the stroke for **25%** --> the value of end angle = **0pi**, 
for **50%** --> end angle = **-0.5pi**, 
and on same note for **100%** --> end angle = **-1.5pi**

here is the formula to calculate the same:

```
endAngle = (0.5 - (2 * percentageForProgress)) * .pi
```